# Conflicting types - Function

Tags: objective-c

The following code leads to "Conflicting types for 'testf'". Does anybody have an idea?

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
}
@end
```

.m:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
@implementation RootViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *testString=testf(1);
}
NSString* testf(int x){
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
    NSString *infstr=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*x)]];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return infstr;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Although this is a stripped down version of my original code, it doesn't work either.

The exact error is "Conflicting types for 'testf'". There are also a couple of warnings, including "Implicit declaration of function 'testf' is invalid in C99".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to declare the prototype of your testf function somewhere, before calling it:

```
NSString* testf(int x);
```

Either do that in the .h, or in the .m

Answer (score 1):

You have a declaration of `testf` (in a header, or earlier in the same file) that does not match the implementation that you listed here.

Comment: I thought so at first, but I just took a new blank project and tried it - same error.

Comment: @Fsch: what headers are included in the file?

Comment: Nothing except the declaration of RootViewController:UITableViewController

Comment: @Fsch: clearly not; otherwise you wouldn't have the headers for NSDateFormatter or NSString.  So again, what headers are included?  Also, please add the exact error message to your question.

Comment: @Fsch - If the code isn't too long, post all the source and header files of exactly what you are trying to do.